# Java : 64 based string decode / parse failed

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, flexjson

I am trying to convert this 64 based encoded JSON string and convert received JSON into POJO using flexjson API.

First try block, converts direct JSON as string into object which is success. This string is decoded using online tool.

Now second try block, try to convert 64 based string into an object in a similar way but converting the 64based string on the run which is throwing exception **flexjson.JSONException: Expected a ',' or ']' at character 10**

```
 try {
        AsyncResponseDO asyncResponseDO = new JSONDeserializer<AsyncResponseDO>().deserialize("{\"relatesTo\":\"7_Sept2017_IF01\"}", AsyncResponseDO.class);
        System.out.println(asyncResponseDO.getRelatesTo());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

try {
        AsyncResponseDO asyncResponseDO = new JSONDeserializer<AsyncResponseDO>().deserialize(Base64.decodeBase64("eyJyZWxhdGVzVG8iOiI3X1NlcHQyMDE3X0lGMDEifQ==".getBytes()).toString(), AsyncResponseDO.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

POJO class :

```
public class AsyncResponseDO {
private String relatesTo; 

public String getRelatesTo() {
    return relatesTo;
}
public void setRelatesTo(String relatesTo) {
    this.relatesTo = relatesTo;
}
}
```

Comment: What is `getBytes` supposed to achieve there? Does `Base64.decodeBase64` not take a simple text literal/string as parameter?

Comment: @CBroe No, It only accepts byte[]

byte[] org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(byte[] arg0)

Comment: @CBroe 

byte[] decodeBase64(String base64String) is available since 1.4 and I am on 1.2.

Comment: Have you at least checked what that results in, before you decode it as JSON?

Comment: new String(Base64.decodeBase64("eyJyZWxhdGVzVG8iOiI3X1NlcHQyMDE3X0lGMDEifQ==".getBytes()));

Comment: Above thing solved my problem. I thank all the people who responded. and people who gave -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**new String**(Base64.decodeBase64("eyJyZWxhdGVzVG8iOiI3X1NlcHQyMDE3‌X0lGMDEifQ==".getByt‌es()));

This will convert into a proper string.

I referred to https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-byte-array-to-string-in-java/